# Differentiability Piecewise function

Tags: derivatives, piecewise-continuity

**Problem 13- Chapter 9- Spivak**

Let $f(x)=x^2$ if x is rational, and $f(x)=0$ if x is irrational. Prove that at x=0 f is differentiable.

**What I did:**
In this problem, all I was able to do was to see that f(x) is continuous at x=0 and that
$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(h)}{h}}$. From there, that if h is rational $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{h}=0$ and if h is irrational $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{0}=0$. But I could not formalize it to be a valid solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = 0$, where $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \in \Bbb Q \\ 0 & x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \end{cases}$:

The required proposition can be simplied to $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = 0$.

Using the epsilon-delta of limit, our proposition becomes $\forall\varepsilon>0: \exists\delta>0: 0<|h|<\delta \implies \left\vert\dfrac{f(h)}h\right\vert<\varepsilon$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

We claim that $\delta=\varepsilon$ satisfies the proposition:

Let $h$ be a real number such that $0<|h|<\delta$.

If $h$ is rational, then $\dfrac{f(h)}h = \dfrac{h^2}h=h<\delta=\varepsilon$. (Why doesn't it fail for $h=0$?)

If $h$ is irrational, then $\dfrac{f(h)}h=\dfrac0h=0<\varepsilon$.

Hence, we conclude that $\left\vert\dfrac{f(h)}h\right\vert<\varepsilon$.

Comment: It doesn't fail for h=0 because $\varepsilon>0$, right?

Comment: @Fhoenix no, it isn't the reason. $\dfrac{f(h)}h$ would not be defined if $h=0$.

Comment: I get that $f(h)/h$ is not defined if h=0, but I don't understand why it doesn't fail for h=0.

Comment: @Fhoenix that is exactly what I told you to ponder upon.

Comment: Oooh, the continuity of f(x) at x=0!

Comment: @Fhoenix no, $f(h)/h$ would still be not defined.

Comment: I spent the last day trying to figure it out and was not able to arrive at anything. @Kenny, why is it?

Comment: @Fhoenix Because "$h$ be a real number such that $0<|h|<\delta$", i.e. $h$ will never be $0$ (this is why we have $0<$ in the definition of limit, so that we won't need to take care of the value exactly at that point).

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\frac{f(h)}h=\begin{cases}h&\text{ if }h\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\\0&\text{ if }h\text{ is irrational,}\end{cases}$$then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\varepsilon$, then$$|h|<\delta=\varepsilon\implies\left|\frac{f(h)}h\right|<\varepsilon.$$So, this proves, by the definition of limit, that$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}h=0.$$

Comment: Just 13 seconds...